# How to connect to network related Printers (WiFi) in ionic app and print data

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am developing an restaurant menu application where user can order items from his table and after ordering it has to print to printing devices at the desk.

Where the printing device is Network connected machine so please help me how to connect to printing device and print the data.

Comment: you can use this, https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/printer

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sharma i tried the printer plugin it is not showing any available printers. printer.IsAvailable()

Comment: Hi did you solve this issue ?